How does the Suzuki sporadic group act on an extraspecial group?
According to the ATLAS of Finite Groups, the centralizer of a 3B element in the Monster is the nonsplit extension 31+12.2Suz, where 31+12 is an extraspecial group, and 2Suz is the double cover of Suzuki's sporadic group. I thought that the 12-dimensional representation of the Suzuki group is an orthogonal representation, but the automorphism group of the extraspecial group is the double cover of the symplectic group. Given that these facts seem contradictory, how exactly does the double cover of the Suzuki group act on the extraspecial group?

$2.{\rm Suz}$ is a maximal subgroup of ${\rm Sp}(12,3)$, so it looks as though you were wrong about the representation being orthogonal. I can post a couple of $12 \times 12$ generating matrices of $2.{\rm Suz}$ if you like!

$3.{\rm Suz}$ is a maximal subgroup of ${\rm SU}(12,2)$, but that's not orthogonal either.

I think I figured it out. Thanks.
